# nctidy not opening file that previously worked. Returning error Tibble columns must have compatible sizes

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, netcdf

I have been using the same script to open the NOAA nClimGrid nc files (https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/data-in-development/nclimgrid/catalog.html) for months using tidync().

As of this morning I get the following error (yet the file opens just fine with ncdf4). I have updated R and all packages and have tried using different netcdf files of different datasets, all with same result.

Error: Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
• Size 2: Columns filter_id and filter_params.
• Size 3: Column chunksizes.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any insights?

I get the same error when using stars::read_ncdf() and nc_vars(). I've submitted a ticket on tidync() but am wondering if something broke with ncmeta or RNetCDF.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: The issue is with the ncmeta package. Installing the dev version, as described in this link resolves the problem.

https://github.com/hypertidy/ncmeta/issues/42